# Gaussian process regression: (i) fit evaluation; (ii) application to purely stochastic time series

Tags: regression, gaussian-process

I am just starting the learn about GPR, and have two questions which
I've not seen addressed in the material I've read:
(i) In my regression courses, emphasis was placed on the examination
of the fit residuals, in order to ensure that the model was appropriate
(e.g. non-random residuals show that a straight line does not model
a quadratic very well). Is there an equivalent for GPR? In other words,
are there goodness-of-fit procedures?
(ii) Is there anything to be gained from applying GPR to purely stochastic
time series such as ARMA processes?

Comment: FWIW: Gaussian Processes are a general stochastic process. Linear models and ARMA processes are special cases of a GP

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question as to the utility of applying GPR to ARMA time series (which, btw, do not have to be Gaussian).

Comment: Essentially, with a GP you will get a reasonable approximation due to the flexibility. However, the approach will be inefficient if you are aware or ARMA structure or linear structure